# Difference between MappingProxyType and PEP 416 frozendict

Tags: python, python-3.x, immutability

While `frozendict` [was rejected](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0416/#rejection-notice), a related class `types.MappingProxyType` was added to public API in python 3.3.

I understand `MappingProxyType` is just a wrapper around the underlying `dict`, but despite that isn't it functionally equivalent to `frozendict`?

In other words, what's the substantive difference between the original PEP 416 `frozendict` and this:

```
from types import MappingProxyType
def frozendict(*args, **kwargs):
  return MappingProxyType(dict(*args, **kwargs))
```

Of course `MappingProxyType` is not hashable as is, but just as [the PEP suggested for `frozendict`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0416/#recipe-hashable-dict), it can be made hashable after ensuring that all its values are hashable (MappingProxyType cannot be subclassed, so it would be require composition and forwarding of methods).

Answer (score 28):

### TL;DR

`MappingProxyType` is a read only proxy for mapping (e.g. dict) objects.

`frozendict` is an immutable dict

### Answer

The proxy pattern is (quoting [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_pattern)):

> A proxy, in its most general form, is a class functioning as an
>   interface to something else.

The `MappingProxyType` is just a simple proxy (i.e. interface) to access the real object (the real map, which on our example is dict).

the suggested `frozendict` object is just as set is to frozenset. a read only  (immutable) object which can only be changed upon creation.

So why do we need `MappingProxyType`? example use case is where you want to pass a dictionary to another function but without it able to change your dictionary, it act as a read only proxy, (quoting [python docs](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/types.html#types.MappingProxyType)):

> Read-only proxy of a mapping. It provides a dynamic view on the
>   mapping’s entries, which means that when the mapping changes, the view
>   reflects these changes.

lets see some example usage of the `MappingProxyType`

```
In [1]: from types import MappingProxyType
In [2]: d = {'a': 1, 'b': 2}
In [3]: m = MappingProxyType(d)
In [4]: m['a']
Out[4]: 1
In [5]: m['a'] = 5
TypeError: 'mappingproxy' object does not support item assignment
In [6]: d['a'] = 42
In [7]: m['a']
Out[7]: 42
In [8]: for i in m.items():
...:     print(i)

('a', 42)
('b', 2)
```

### Update:

because the PEP did not make it into python, we cannot know for sure what the implementation that would be.
by looking at the PEP we see that:

```
frozendict({'a': {'b': 1}})
```

would raise an exception as `{'b': 1}` is not hashable value, but on your implementation it will create the object. of-course, you can add a validation for the value as noted on the PEP.

I assume part of the PEP was memory optimization and implementation of this kind of frozendict could have benefit from the performance of dict comparison using the `__hash__` implementation.

Comment: Yes, but my question was whether there's any substantial difference between the rejected `frozendict` and the one you can create as a thin wrapper around `MappingProxyType`. Can you give example of some code that would work with the (rejected) PEP 416 `frozendict` but would not work with the `frozendict` that I defined in my question?

Comment: frozendict would enable to use dictionaries as key or make a set of dictionaries. MappingProxyType objects can't be used as dict key or set elements since they could be mutated indirectly during their life cycle, potentially breaking the uniqueness invariant.

Comment: So, the differences so far are 1) MPT isn't hashable, and thus has a wider range of acceptable keyvalues, and 2) MPT isn't subclassable. Why isn't it subclassable?

Comment: @Dubslow. If I had to guess, it's because the C magic that implements it says so. Here is the C interface: https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/dict.html#c.PyDictProxy_New

Comment: Well, in theory you can create a MappingProxyType this way: MappingProxyType({1: 2}). The original dict is not accessible by anything after this code. The real problem with MappingProxyType is that it is *very* slow.

Comment: @MarcoSulla real world usually involves nested mutable objects. Such as {'a':{'b': [1,2]}} which might lead to undesired results when using MappingProxyType. Unlike correctness, Speed is not always a concern.

Comment: @ShmulikA yes, and this is normal. It's not required that all the objects in the immutable object must be immutable. For example, tuple is an immutable type, but you can have a tuple of lists. In this case, the tuple simply is not hashable. If you want deep immutability, there's gelidum: https://github.com/diegojromerolopez/gelidum

Answer (score 10):

MappingProxyType add immutability only on a first level:

```
>>> from types import MappingProxyType
>>> d = {'a': {'b': 1}}
>>> md = MappingProxyType(d)
>>> md
mappingproxy({'a': {'b': 1}})
>>> md['a']['b']
1
>>> md['a']['b'] = 3
>>> md['a']['b']
3
```

Comment: This is obviously the same with frozendict...

Answer (score 2):

`MappingProxyType` is also terribly slow. I suggest you to use [frozendict](https://pypi.org/project/frozendict/)

PS: I'm the new owner of the package

Answer (score 1):

One thing I've noticed is that `frozendict.copy` supports add/replace (limited to string keys), whereas `MappingProxyType.copy` does not. For instance:

```py
d = {'a': 1, 'b': 2} 

from frozendict import frozendict
fd = frozendict(d)
fd2 = fd.copy(b=3, c=5)

from types import MappingProxyType
mp = MappingProxyType(d)
# mp2 = mp.copy(b=3, c=5) => TypeError: copy() takes no keyword arguments
# to do that w/ MappingProxyType we need more biolerplate
temp = dict(mp)
temp.update(b=3, c=5)
mp2 = MappingProxyType(temp)
```

Note: none of these two immutable maps supports "remove and return new immutable copy" operation.